Binary predictive classification in R, with predictors consisting of multiple values
I am struggling currently with constructing a binary glm predictive classifier, due to an issue with dimensionality.
I have a dataset of N samples where each sample has values for M entries (genes) and is either Case or Control. However, each gene consists of 1 ... k datapoints for each sample, where each datapoint is a numerical value ranging from 0 to 1 representative of the methylation of a CpG site overlapping the gene. And the number of datapoints varies in turn for each gene (thus meaning that each gene is represented by a dataframe of varying size). The classifier is supposed to be binary, assigning samples as Case/Control based on the values for a set of predictors (genes) which are chosen through cross-validation.
I have previously constructed binary predictive classifiers where one value for each sample was representative of a gene (i.e. from a NxM dataframe), but i am stuck on how to handle the current scenario where each 1...M column in my NxM dataframe could be said to actually be a NxK dataframe rather then a Nx1 column.
I have thought to represent the NxK dataframe as a Nx1 column through taking the median value out of the 1...k datapoints for each of the N samples, or by choosing one column in the NxK dataframe to represent the dataframe (based on selection critera that is fitting for my research question), but ideally I would like to point towards the NxK dataframe representing the gene, when constructing the classifier.
Does anyone have experience with this type of problem, and if so is it even possible to construct a predictive classifier from a dataframe of predictors, where the predictors in turn point towards separate dataframes?
If not, is my approach of taking the median value out of the 1...k datapoints for each sample a valid approach?
I have previously constructed classifiers where each gene was represented by one value, however i have no experience with this type of problem.

Could you please edit the question to say more about what the "k datapoints for each [gene in a] sample" represent in practice? There might be some way to simplify this based on subject-matter knowledge; some of us have subject-matter knowledge in biology that might help complement yours.

I have edited the post to better explain what these mean. But essentially, as they all represent a biological measurement, using the median value risks minimizing actual biological variance, while choosing the most variable probe instead risks making the model prone to overfitting (or selecting a probe which shows variance in my data, but not in the external validation cohorts).
Hence, the ideal solution would be to treat the probes overlapping the gene(s) as a set, which are all taken into account when training the model.

This is more an issue of subject-matter knowledge than statistical analysis per se. I don't know of a way to use matrices of different dimensions as predictors (perhaps someone else on this site does), but you can choose any way that makes sense numerically and biologically to reduce those matrices to a convenient number of predictor values for each gene.
The question to ask is what measure derived from the CpG methylation data is most likely to provide information for your modeling task. The median is certainly one such choice. Others would include the mean or a measure of variability among the individual "datapoints."
In particular, heterogeneity of CpG methylation is increasingly recognized as important on its own, for regions that are intermediate between almost no methylation (say, < 5% methylated) and almost complete methylation (> 95% methylated). For example, Zhang and Wang, Bioinformatics. 2022 Jun 24;38(Suppl 1):i307-i315, provide tools to distinguish three types of intermediate CpG methylation patterns:

we borrowed the naming of three canonical methylation patterns in intermediately methylated regions from a previous study where the ‘identical’ methylation pattern represents a pattern with high consistency between reads but low concordance across adjacent CpG sites; the ‘disordered’ methylation pattern represents a pattern with low concordance both between reads and CpG sites; the ‘uniform’ methylation pattern represents a pattern with highly concordant CpG sites within single reads but large differences between some reads

Using a biologically relevant way to extract information from your CpG data should be superior to any generic choice based solely on statistical principles.
